# Converting IPython Notebooks from v4 (Jupyter) back to good ol' v3

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is there a way to convert new notebook versions (v4, Jupyter) back to the old format (v3)? At my university all machines in the computer pool are equipped with v3 (sigh!) but I've been using Jupyter for a while now. The problem is though, that we do a lot of teaching based on notebooks (they are great for tutorials and such), but it is a shame that the students cannot use mine since they cannot open them on their computers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This you can find in the [documentation](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) of `nbconvert`:

> ```
> jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --nbformat 3 mynotebook
> ```
>
> will create a copy of mynotebook.ipynb in mynotebook.v3.ipynb in
>   version 3 of the notebook format.
>
> If you want to convert a notebook in-place, you can specify the ouptut
>   file to be the same as the input file:
>
> ```
> jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --nbformat 3 mynb --output mynb
> ```
>
> Be careful with
>   that, since it will replace the input file.